# How to use a search bar with Python

Tags: python, excel, search, searchbar

Right now I am trying to figure out how to take a row of data, maybe like 50 entries max, and enter it individually into a search bar. But first I need to understand the beginning concepts so I want to do a practice program that could take info from an Excel sheet and enter into a Google search or YouTube, for example.

My problem is there seems to be no resource on how to do this for beginners. All posts I have read are either parts of the whole problem or not related to actually using a search bar but instead creating one. Even then every post I read has 100 plug-ins I could possibly add.

I'm just looking for a consistent explanation to where I can grasp how I can manipulate code in order to use a search bar function.

Comment: Do you mean you are trying to submit data to a Google (or YouTube) search, i.e. use your data to perform a search?

Comment: You can use csv module to read excel files that were saved as csv.  If you must read excel in native mode, use xlrdr module.  To search, look at a url that is created by the search engine when you create a manual search with several terms.

Comment: Can you elaborate on that? Im trying to break down this problem into two steps. First step is try and figure out how to use a searchbar using python. Google and youtube are simply examples. The real project that requires it is something for work to search a database. part two would be grabbing the contents of an excel cell and placing it into the search bar. So my question at this point is how do I write a program that can access a webpage that has the search bar then input data into it?

Answer (score 0):

To perform a web search (Google, YouTube or whatever) from a program you need to execute the search, either by building up and calling an appropriate search URL or by making a call to an API provided by that site.

The article '[Python - Search for YouTube video](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/873060/Python-Search-Youtube-for-Video)' provides a code sample and explanation of how to generate and call a URL to perform a YouTube keyword search. You could do something similar for a Google search by analysing the URL from the result of a Google search, or try searching for 'Python submit google search url'.

The above approach is simplistic and relies on the URL structure for a particular site staying the same. A more complex, reliable and flexible approach is to use the API. For YouTube:

- [YouTube API - Python developers guide](https://developers.google.com/youtube/1.0/developers_guide_python)
- [YouTube API - Python code samples - Search by keyword](https://developers.google.com/youtube/v3/code_samples/python#search_by_keyword)